# Как присвоить событию нажатия на кнопку, выполняемое действие C#, WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, события

У меня есть метод, который при нужном мне условии, ставит IsEnabled = true у кнопки.
Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку очистилось поле,пытаюсь присвоить событию нажатия на кнопки нужное мне действие (Очистка поля). Выдает ошибку.
Не удается неявно преобразовать тип Void в System.Windows.Routed.Event.Handler.
Как решить эту проблему?

```
        private void ClearGameField()
        {
        if(GameField.Children.Count==2)
        {
            Bito.IsEnabled = true;
            Bito.Click += GameField.Children.Clear();//Вот в этом месте ошибка 
        }

        }
```

Comment: Использовать подписку на событие? Указать функцию нужной сигнатуры? Подписка на событие это настолько базовая вещь, что вы и без помощи сами можете найти информацию, как это сделать.

Comment: Bito.Click += GameField.Children.Clear() // это не подписка на событие?
как она должна выглядеть

Comment: `Bito.Click += (s, e) => GameField.Children.Clear();`

Answer (score 0):

В конструкторе делаем подписку на событие командой: `Bito.Click += ClearGameField;`
А в методе добавляем параметры `(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e);`

```cs
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Bito.Click += ClearGameField;
}

private void ClearGameField(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(GameField.Children.Count==2)
    {
        GameField.Children.Clear();
    }
}
```